# Getting error while installing an unlocked package in a Scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, package-install

sfdx-project.json ->

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "GIFter",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT"
        },
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "package": "GIFter1",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "default": false
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "47.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "GIFter": "0Ho2w000000XZIaCAO",
        "GIFter1": "0Ho2w000000XZIfCAO"
    }
}
```

Using Command -> `$ sfdx force:package:install --wait 10 --publishwait 10 --package GIFter@1.0.0-1 -k test1234 --noprompt`

Error -> `ERROR running force:package:install:  Invalid alias or ID: GIFter@1.0.0-1. Either your alias is invalid or undefined, or the ID provided is invalid.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Package Version before you can install a package. Run the following command first:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -x -p GIFter -w 100 -v devhuborgalias
```

Once you do that, you'll be able to run an installation command as you expect.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to create a version. Thankyou @sfdcfox :)